# C# database connection and datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, odbc

I recently started using databases in C# but I'm not figuring out something!
In Visual Studio 2008 I started a new project, added a datagridview to the form, and on form_load I put this code:

```
string strCon = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Numeratori.accdb;";
string strSql = "select * from tabela";
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(strCon);
con.Open();
OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
dadapter.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(strSql, con);
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
dadapter.Fill(dset);
con.Close();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dset;
```

When I run it the form opens up but in the datagridview there is no data!
what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

A DataSet can contain multiple DataTables.  You could set the DataGridView's data source to a specific table in the DataSet, or just use a DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
dadapter.Fill(table);
con.Close();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

On a side note, you can use `using` to help clean up resources:

```
string strCon = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Numeratori.accdb;";
string strSql = "select * from tabela";

using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(strCon))
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql, con))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dadapter.Fill(table);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: thnx for the answer :D just tried this but still the same problem the datagridview is empty :\

Comment: @user670255, hmm... this should work.  Just to check, are you sure there is data in that table?  If you put a breakpoint on the line where you set `dataGridView1.DataSource = table;`, is there data in `table`?

Comment: yes it is! i created the columns in ms access and added some data in rows! i also tried to do it not from form load but with a button click and now i came up with an error: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: @user670255, the only other thing I can think of is that [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) is `false`.  `true` is the default value, but you might want to check and make sure.  Other then that, I tried code similar to this using Sql Server, and it filled the data grid.  I don't have much experience w/ Access, so can't help with your other error.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
        SqlConnection sql_connect = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand();
        string connetionString = @"server=ALI-LAP\SQLEXPRESSR2;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=XXX;";

         SqlDataAdapter sql_ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                sql_connect.ConnectionString = connetionString;
                sql_command.Connection = sql_connect;
                sql_command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM XXX";

                sql_ada.SelectCommand = sql_command;
                sql_ada.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help, add these lines to the last of your coding line:

```cs
this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "tabela";
```

and better put this line before `con.Close();`

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dset;
this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "tabela";
```